# When to use billingclient:billing in android app?

Tags: android, android-billing, billingclient

My Android app doesn't have any subscription or in app purchase, do I need to use billingclient library in my app?
Is it mandatory to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't have any products that can be purchased via Google Play, you don't need Billing Library.